# Trouble to compile both *eps and and png (or jpg) together

Tags: graphics, eps, png

I have been trying to compile both *eps, it works with  % !TEX TS-program = latex but I can not compile *eps format with other formats like PNG or JPG, I am using Texstudio with Mac (especially with ARARA engine ) Please let me know, below the Minimal example

```
% !TEX TS-program = latex
 \documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{graphicx}
% \DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf,.jpeg,.png}

 \begin{document}


    \begin{figure}[h]
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{example1}
        \caption{Comparison of all results for V notch specimen}
        \label{fig:figure38}
    \end{figure}
 \begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=1.3\textwidth]{figure38}
    \caption{Ya rab}
 \end{figure}

 \end{document}
```

Comment: Remove the `\DeclareGraphicsExtensions` line. `graphicx` declares rules to deal with all these formats, if you don't override what it is trying to do. If you use `pdflatex`, the EPS will be automatically converted to PDF. If you use `latex`, you may need to convert some files yourself - I'm not sure. `pdflatex` will be easiest here as it supports everything directly, except the EPS, and that's easily auto-converted.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply. I still haven't solved the problem. the problem in the png file, ( the error message was appeared is the following: (example1 not found )). or (can not determine the size)
Looking to receiving any help.

Comment: LaTeX can only deal with `eps` graphics. Compile with `pdflatex` which is now able to convert `eps` to `PDF` on the fly in recent TeX distributions. The conversion is `file.eps`->`file-eps-converted-to.pdf` which then imported by `pdftex`.

Comment: Thanks, herb Schulz, but I had complied successfully with PNG or JPG. The problem is I can compile files successfully with PNG and JPG or files include 8eps but together I can not.